# Access cards outside my glass app

Tags: android-studio, google-glass

Is it possible to access card outside your application in android studio? Im trying to catch data from a card which been sent through an google API mirror to my glass using apache server.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit on what, exactly, you're trying to do? Are you trying to debug problems you're having with the mirror API (items on the timeline) or with the GDK (apps appearing in the "now" section of the timeline)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about access other applications' card using yours, then the answer is no. There is no way you can grab information without the right permission.

Or.. if you are talking about updating your own card, you use [Live Cards](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards).

Comment: Thanks for reply, We are now using a Webserivce that send static cards using Mirror API to our glass through the site, console.developer gg project. We also created an application in android studio that we want to send those static cards to. But if I understand is impossible to send those cards to our application? If so should we just use Mirror API and send static cards to the glasses? We are not really trying to access card outside our application we just want the webservice to send those static cards directly to our own application.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I will be more specific. What I want is to send static cards from a mirror API to my app in my glasses. Then use those static cards, or view them in my notification menu in my app. Is it possible to send static cards from a Mirror API to my app? Im using Android studio.